# Quotienting by kernel of a monoid homomorphism in the integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, integers, group-isomorphism, monoid

If $f : \Bbb{Z}^{\times} \to (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ is a monoid hom, then is $\Bbb{Z}^{\times} / \ker f \approx \operatorname{im} f$?  For example $f(x) = x^2$.

That is can we quotient a monoid by the kernel of a monoid hom?

$\Bbb{Z}^{\times}$ the monoid not the group of units!

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is $({\Bbb Z}/n)^\times$? Do you mean $f(x) = (x^2 \bmod n)$? How do you define $\ker f$ and ${\Bbb Z}^\times/{\ker f}$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Not the OP, but $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is another way of writing the ring of integers modulo $n$ ($\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$), so I would imagine $\mathbb{Z}^\times$ to be the multiplicative monoid of the integers and $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$ to be the multiplicative monoid of the integers modulo $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a monoid homomorphism. If by $\text{ker}(f)$, you mean $\{x\in M\mid f(x) = e\}$, where $e$ is the identity element of $N$, then $\text{ker}(f)$ is a submonoid of $M$, but it's not clear what $M/\text{ker}(f)$ means. There's not a general "quotient by a subobject" construction for monoids.

On the other hand, if by $\text{ker}(f)$ you mean the equivalence relation $\{(x,y)\mid f(x) = f(y)\}$, then $\text{ker}(f)$ is a congruence on $M$, and the quotient $M/\text{ker}(f)$ makes sense and is a monoid isomorphic to $\text{im}(f)$. This follows from the first isomorphism theorem of universal algebra (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#General), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)#Monoid_homomorphisms) for the special case of monoids).